# using popup with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i am showing a popup on the click of particular option on the dropdown 
in the popup i am using a textbox and a save button
on the click of save button the value of the textbox was saved into the database

now i want to show the currently add option in to the dropdown.
i am unable to show it in the dropdown.

i am using the following code

```
 var myselect = $('Select');
                var othercountry = getValue1("txtCountry");
                $.each(othercountry, function (val, text) {
                    othercountry.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));

                })
```

Comment: what does getValue1 do? what id othercountry?

Comment: function getValue1(Id) {
        return $.trim($('#' + Id).val());
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
var option = $('<option />');
$('#select').append(option);

option.val('valueToAdd').html('visibleText');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a demo of what I think you are asking for... Let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/AZ5Sm/44/